# How can i select the id of each person who made a reservation in ALL hotels in paris. Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables
person, hotel and a reservation table

How can i select the id of each person who made a reservation in ALL hotels in paris.

```
Hotels
Hotel Croissaint
Hotel Baguette
Hotel Fromage 

Person
Jean
Pierre
Marc
Anthony
Bastian
```

Jean  **reserved** Hotel Croissaint

Pierre **reserved** Hotel Croissaint, Hotel Baguette and Hotel Fromage (Reserved All)

Marc  **reserved** Hotel Croissaint, Hotel Baguette and Hotel Fromage (Reserved All)

Anthony **reserved** Hotel Croissaint, Hotel Baguette

Bastian  **reserved** no hotel

I want to get Pierre and Marc , because they reserved all hotels and not just 1, or 2 or none

Note: If you can do it **without** analytic functions the better

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE]. Particularly: your table structures (preferably as DDL statements we can copy/paste and execute); how your sample data is stored in those tables (preferably as DML statements); and what you have attempted to answer the question. From your question it is unclear if you are storing the reservation list in multiple rows per user or as a single delimited string. Also, why the arbitrary restriction of not using analytic functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the hotels are only in Paris, you would sue:

```
select person
from reservations
group by persons
having count(distinct hotel) = (select count(*) from hotels);
```

If not all hotels are in Paris, then perhaps there is a location indicator:

```
select person
from reservations
group by persons
having count(distinct hotel) = (select count(*) from hotels where location = 'Paris');
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and then `having` which allows you to filter by aggregated values. In this case you want the distinct count of hotels e.g.

```
select person_name, count(distinct hotel) as n
from reservations
group by person_name
having count(distinct hotel) = 4
```

nb: without column names or tables names supplied to us via "sample data" we can only make guesses

Answer (score 0):

From the information that you have provided it looks like the reservation table will have the hotel_id and the person_id, you can do a as follows.

```
--UNTESTED

    SELECT PERSON_ID, CITY, reseervation_city_count FROM
    (
    Select p.person_id, p.person_nm , re.city ,  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY re.person_id,re.city) as reseervation_city_count
    FROM  PERSON P
    JOIN RESERVATION RE ON P.PERSON_ID = RE.PERSON_ID
    ) JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) CNT , CITY FROM HOTEL GROUP BY CITY) HOTEL_COUNT  
    ON  HOTEL_COUNT.HOTEL_COUNT AND HOTEL_COUNT.CITY = RESERVATION .CITY
```